# cannot find package with running go build

Tags: environment-variables, path

```
root@kali:~/subfinder# go build
main.go:15:2: cannot find package 
"github.com/subfinder/subfinder/libsubfinder/helper" in any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.11/src/github.com/subfinder/subfinder/libsubfinder/helper 
(from $GOROOT)
    /root/go
/src/github.com/subfinder/subfinder/libsubfinder/helper (from $GOPATH)
main.go:16:2: cannot find package "github.com/subfinder/subfinder/subf" in 
any of:
    /usr/lib/go-1.11/src/github.com/subfinder/subfinder/subf (from $GOROOT)
    /root/go
/src/github.com/subfinder/subfinder/subf (from $GOPATH)
```

Here is my go path version:

```
root@kali:~# go version
go version go1.11.4 linux/386
```

My Go ENV:

```
root@kali:~# go env
GOARCH="386"
GOBIN="/root/go_projects/bin"
GOCACHE="/root/.cache/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/root/go
"
GOPROXY=""
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.11"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.11/pkg/tool/linux_386"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GO386="387"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m32 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix- 
map=/tmp/go- 
build284184378=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

My .profile

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
      if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
 fi
 fi

 mesg n || true

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export GOPATH="$HOME/go_projects"
export GOBIN="$GOPATH/bin"
```

Answer (score 4):

Golang is quite opinionated regarding which directories your source must be in. (And yet, it often doesn't give you a helpful or actionable error message about that.)

In any case, if your package is named `github.com/subfinder/subfinder`, then in order to build it you need to have the sources for it stored under `$GOPATH/src/github.com/subfinder/subfinder`, which in your case would be `/root/go/src/github.com/subfinder/subfinder` (from the environment listing, not the `.profile`.)

One way to ensure it will be checked out in the right location is to use `go get` to fetch it (and optionally build/install it.) Using `go get` with the `-d` option will simply download the sources, so you can modify them and build them if you need to do that in a separate step.

```
$ go get -d github.com/subfinder/subfinder
```

This command will fetch it into the first directory in your `$GOPATH` (which can actually be a list of directories separated by `:`, similar to how `$PATH` works, in the unlikely case you want to search multiple base directories for the packages.)

---

In your post, there's also a disconnect between the environment listing (which says `GOPATH="/root/go"`) and the `.profile` (which says `GOPATH="$HOME/go_projects"`.) I imagine that's because you're listing the `.profile` of a non-root user, while you're running the `go build` and listing the environment as root? Or maybe you have another issue causing your `.profile` not to be read, for instance not a login shell, or you have another profile file such as `.bash_profile` which takes precedence, etc.

It seems you also have an issue with a trailing newline in the `$GOPATH` setting of root (you can see the double quote only closes on the second line), which *might* be causing some of these problems... So to be sure you should probably try to fix that as well.